# In normative order evaluation, is there distinction between call by value, call by reference, call by sharing, etc?

Tags: programming-languages

Consider different ways of evaluating a procedure call and its arguments.
*Essentials of Programming Languages* says

> All the parameter-passing mechanisms (natural parameter passing, call by value, call by reference) we have discussed so far are eager:
>   they always ﬁnd a value for each operand. We now turn to a very different
>   form of parameter passing, called lazy evaluation.

What I understand it is that:

- In applicative order evaluation (eager evaluation), we distinguish between call by value, call by reference, call by sharing, etc.
- In normal order evaluation (lazy evaluation), is there still similar distinction  between call by value, call by reference, call by sharing, etc?

Comment: All three can be combined with lazy evaluation (compute as needed). Not that all necessarily make much sense...

Comment: I think there is a similar distinction even when evaluation type is lazy. Lazy evaluation is type of evaluation in which the question is "when" the parameters will be evaluated, not "how" the parameters will be evaluated, so I think, distinction should still hold.